# Stochastic inequality, true?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider two stochastic processes $X$ and $Y$ satisfying the following SDEs (with the same drift!):

$$X_t = x + \int_0^t b(X_s)ds + B_t$$

$$Y_t = y + \int_0^t b(Y_s)ds + B_t.$$

If $0<x<y$, is it then true that the sample paths of $Y$ are a.s. bigger than the sample paths of $X$? In other words.. is it true that
$$P(\forall~ t \ Y_t>X_t)=1?$$
If it is true, I don't see how to prove it! :( Btw. the drifts are not Lipschitz so I'm not allowed to use Gronwall here.
Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Do you have any requirements on $b$?

Comment: just bounded.. or.. the weakest requirements so that the statement holds true.

Comment: It is still not clear. If realization of $B_t$ is the same for $X_t$ and $Y_t$ then you just have 2 paths for each $B_t$, and everything is determined by function $b$. Am I wrong?

Comment: I think you are right.. but the drift is acting on different processes.. I would bet the inequality holds true but I don't see an argument

Comment: I'm not convinced this is true, but I haven't proved it yet. My first thought was to choose positive $k$ and $c$, then set $b( r )=-kr$ for $r>c$; $b( r )=kr$ for $r<c$; and $b ( r )=0$ for r=c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim holds true if there exists a *unique* solution to the SDE

$$dZ_t = b(Z_t) \, dt + dB_t, \qquad Z_0 = z \tag{1}$$

e.g. if $b$ is locally Lipschitz continuous.

**Proof:** Let $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ and $(Y_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be solutions to the SDEs

$$\begin{align*} dX_t &= b(X_t) \, dt + dB_t \qquad X_0 = x \tag{2} \\ dY_t &= b(Y_t) \, dt + dB_t \qquad Y_0 = y \tag{3}\end{align*}$$ for $x<y$. We define a stopping time $\tau$ by

$$\tau := \inf\{t>0; X_t > Y_t\}$$

where $\inf \emptyset := \infty$. Note that, by the continuity of the solutions, $X_{\tau} =Y_{\tau}$. Now set

$$\tilde{X}_t := \begin{cases} X_t, & t \leq \tau, \\ Y_t, & t>\tau. \end{cases}$$

Obviously, $\tilde{X}_0 = x$ and, moreover,

$$d\tilde{X}_t = b(\tilde{X}_t) \, dt + dB_t.$$

(Intuitively, it should be clear that the last equation holds. Making this rigorous  requires some more effort; note that we do not need any further assumptions on $b$ to do so.) This means that $(\tilde{X}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ solves $(2)$. Consequently, we conclude from the uniqueness of the solution that $$\mathbb{P}(\tau<\infty)=0.$$

Hence,

$$\mathbb{P}(\forall t: X_t \leq Y_t)=1.$$

(Note that in general the equality $\mathbb{P}(\forall t: X_t<Y_t)=1$ does *not* hold.)

**Remark:** This statement is a very particular case of a so-called "comparison principle".

Comment: Yes, pathwise uniqueness holds for very general $b$ so that is fulfilled. It seems to me that to justify that $(\tilde{X}_t)_{t\geq 0}$ also solves (2) is not using any regulairty on $b$. Maybe one could use the existence of a stochastic flow and then using the flow property by solving (2) from 0 to $\tau$ and then further ahead? I really don't see any flaw in Your answer so I Guess that's correct :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Martingalo You are right, in order to see that $(\tilde{X}_t)_t$ solves $(2)$ we do not need regularity of $b$. The regularity is only needed to conclude that the processes $(\tilde{X}_t)_t$ and $(X_t)_t$ coincide.

Comment: Sorry to bother, but I'm having some trouble seeing how the uniqueness of the new process implies that the stopping time is almost never finite. Could someone please elaborate?

Comment: @Bhoot The uniqueness implies that $(\tilde{X}_t)_t = (X_t)_t$. On the other hand, we know from the definition of the stopping time $\tau$ that $\tilde{X}_t < X_t$ for (some) $t>\tau$. Consequently, $\tau=\infty$ almost surely.

Comment: Thanks! But does the proof still hold if you redefine the stopping time as $\tau=\inf\{t>0:X_t=Y_t\}$? As far as I can tell, the proof currently shows that $P(Y_t \geq X_t)=1$, which is true, rather than $P(Y_t>X_t)=1$, which is what the question asked for. If I have missed a basic point and I am just talking on, please ignore me.

Comment: @Bhoot You are right; the solutions can be equal for sufficiently large $t$. (My proof does *not* work if I define $\tau = \inf\{t>0; X_t=Y_t\}$.) Thank you for pointing this out!